# What's the purpose of Q_INTERFACES macro?

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading other people's code and see this:

```
class UAVItem:public QObject,public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
...
```

But I didn't see they are using any sort of plug-in in this program.
Therefore, can I just remove the line:

```
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a class `Derived` which inherits from a class `Base`, which in turn inherits from `QObject`, and both `Derived` and `Base` contain the `Q_OBJECT` macro, then `qobject_cast` can be used to safely cast from a pointer (or reference) to `Base`, to a pointer (or reference) to `Derived`, similar to `dynamic_cast` in standard C++ but without RTTI.

If `Base` does *not* inherit from `QObject`, then `qobject_cast` can still be used in this way, but *only* if `Base` has a corresponding `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` macro and `Derived` contains `Q_INTERFACES(Base)`.

In your case, `Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)` being present in `UAVItem` means that `qobject_cast` can be used to cast from a pointer (or reference) to `QGraphicsItem` to a pointer (or reference) to `UAVItem`, despite `QGraphicsItem` not inheriting from `QObject`.

Answer (score 3):

From [reference doc](https://wiki.qt.io/Plugins),

```
class ToolInterface
{
public:
    virtual QString toolName() const = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(ToolInterface, "in.forwardbias.tool/1.0");

// Hammer in hammer.h (our Hammer plugin)
#include "toolinterface.h"
class Hammer : public QObject, public ToolInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(ToolInterface)
public:
    QString toolName() const { return "hammer"; }
};
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(hammer, Hammer);
```

> When moc runs on the hammer.h code, it inspects Q_INTERFACES. It
>   generates code for a function called qt_metacall - void
>   *Hammer::qt_metacast(const char *iname). This goal of this 'casting' function is to return a pointer to an interface depending on iname.
>   moc also verifies whether the interface names that you have put inside
>   Q_INTERFACES have indeed been declared. It can do this by inspecting
>   the header files and looking for a Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE. In our case,
>   there is a Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE inside toolinterface.h.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my concern is that whether the Q_INTERFACES is able to be used for other situation other than the plugin case? If so, what will it be used for?

Comment: @Nyaruko I use it to silence a warning :D