Using `Q_INTERFACES` and invoking methods in the interfaces
In Qt, I understand that I cannot multiply inherit QObjects. It appears that a QObject can inherit a  Q_GADGET, but it appears that I cannot invoke gadget methods by name. It seems like Qt's Q_INTERFACES features are appropriate for this, but I can't seem to make it work.
My particular use case is I have a collection of classes that I want to use through QML (so their methods are invoked by name by Qt) and I want to mix in different interfaces, so I want to be able to do
class Concrete0 : public QObject, public InterfaceA { ... };
class Concrete1 : public QObject, public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB { ... };

and have the methods exposed by the interface classes be invokable from QML.
Can Q_INTERFACES do this? I've adapted the example from Qt interfaces or abstract classes and qobject_cast() as follows:
class YourInterface {
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual void someMethod() {}
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(YourInterface, "Timothy.YourInterface/1.0")

class OtherInterface {
public:
    // Empty class for now.
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(OtherInterface, "Timothy.OtherInterface/1.0")


class YourClass : public QObject, public YourInterface, public OtherInterface {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(YourInterface OtherInterface)

public:
    YourClass() = default;
};

and to test it:
YourClass* c = new YourClass();
YourInterface* i = qobject_cast<YourInterface*>(c);
assert(i); //< We can qobject_cast it!
const auto& mo = *c->metaObject();
for (auto j = 0; j != mo.methodCount(); ++j) {
    fmt::print("{}\n", mo.method(j).methodSignature().toStdString());
}
fmt::print("\n");
mo.invokeMethod(c, "someMethod");

which prints
destroyed(QObject*)
destroyed()
objectNameChanged(QString)
deleteLater()
_q_reregisterTimers(void*)

qWarning(): QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method YourClass::someMethod()

So it appears that something is working, in that qobject_cast works (and removing the Q_INTERFACES(YourInterface OtherInterface) line makes that fail), but the base-class Q_INVOKABLE virtual void someMethod() {} can't be invoked by name.
How can I make it find someMethod by name? (I can do Q_INVOKABLE void someMethod() override { YourInterface::someMethod(); } in YourClass, but that mostly defeats the purpose of the mixin pattern.

what do you mean "find it by name"?  Q_INVOKABLE  is for operating meta-object system, i.e. invoke using QObject. if function isn't in a QObject, it wouldn't wok.

I mean I want to be able to do c->metaObject()->invokeMethod(c, "someMethod");, which I think(?) is essentially what QML does when I say c.someMethod() in QML.

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558992/1387438

I see that, but it doesn't seem to answer the question of if there's any way to invoke methods by name from the base class. Maybe if the base class is a Q_GADGET?
